# Can not read from socket using BufferedReader.readline()

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to develop a client/Server communication application in java. But at the very initial stage I am unable to read data string from the socket's Output stream using `BufferedReader.readline()`. I have googled a lot but could not find the specific answer to my question.
Debugging the client application shows that the client application halts at `response.readline()`.

Server:

```
package myserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tokens = new String[10];
        int count = 0;
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(16);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OdeskServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (server != null) {
            while (true) {
                PrintWriter response;
                BufferedReader command;
                String inCommand;
                try {
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    System.out.println("Connected!");
                    response = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                    command = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    response.print("EHLO\r\n");
                    command.read(); //just to stop the application to start a new iteration
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OdeskServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package myclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket server = null;
        PrintWriter command;
        BufferedReader response;
        BufferedReader Console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            server = new Socket("175.107.231.218", 16);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            command = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());
            response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            while (server.isBound()) {
                String input = response.readLine(); //Here is where the communication halts
                System.out.print(input);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OdeskClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OdeskClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Testing server.isBound() is pointless. The socket is bound as soon as you connect it, if not sooner, and isBound() isn't going to change afterwards. You should be testing the result of readLine() for null as a loop breaker.

Comment: never mind! I am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to call `response.flush()` from the server to ensure that the socket does not buffer your message waiting for more writes to batch together.